# Why does Numba distort my dtype array while using numpy random shuffle?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shuffle, numba

I'm trying to optimize a  very simple function that goes over every row of a 2D dtype array, assigns some values to its fields, and meanwhile randomly shuffles the order of the members (consider each member a particle that is supposed to interact with other particles and I wish a shuffled order of them per time-step of a simulation). Strangely when I use numba.njit to optimize it, my array gets completely messed up and different. Here's the simple reproducer of my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

D = np.dtype([('f_id','i2'),('p_id','i2'),('x','f8')])
A = np.zeros((3,6),dtype=D)
A['p_id'] = np.arange(6)
B = np.zeros((3,6),dtype=D)
B['p_id'] = np.arange(6)

def test1(x):
for i in range(3):
    y = x[i][:]
    y['f_id'][:] = i
    y['x'][:] = 1000 + i
    np.random.seed(2000)
    np.random.shuffle(y)
return x

@nb.njit
def test2(X):
for ii in range(3):
    Y = X[ii][:]
    Y['f_id'][:] = ii
    Y['x'][:] = 1000 + ii
    np.random.seed(2000)
    np.random.shuffle(Y)
return X

test1(A)
test2(B)
```

first function without njit works fine as expected:

```
A
array([[(0, 1, 1000.), (0, 2, 1000.), (0, 4, 1000.), (0, 5, 1000.),
        (0, 3, 1000.), (0, 0, 1000.)],
       [(1, 1, 1001.), (1, 2, 1001.), (1, 4, 1001.), (1, 5, 1001.),
        (1, 3, 1001.), (1, 0, 1001.)],
       [(2, 1, 1002.), (2, 2, 1002.), (2, 4, 1002.), (2, 5, 1002.),
        (2, 3, 1002.), (2, 0, 1002.)]],
      dtype=[('f_id', '<i2'), ('p_id', '<i2'), ('x', '<f8')])
```

But second function gives weird results every time:

```
B
array([[(0, 0, 1000.), (0, 0, 1000.), (0, 0, 1000.), (0, 0, 1000.),
        (0, 3, 1000.), (0, 0, 1000.)],
       [(1, 0, 1001.), (1, 0, 1001.), (1, 0, 1001.), (1, 0, 1001.),
        (1, 3, 1001.), (1, 0, 1001.)],
       [(2, 0, 1002.), (2, 0, 1002.), (2, 0, 1002.), (2, 0, 1002.),
        (2, 3, 1002.), (2, 0, 1002.)]],
      dtype=[('f_id', '<i2'), ('p_id', '<i2'), ('x', '<f8')])
```

Numba apparently supports random shuffle : http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.22.1/reference/numpysupported.html .

It's worth mentioning that this issue doesn't rise with numpy arrays other than dtype array.

Numba apparently does not recognize numpy random Generator,default_rng(), https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.default_rng.

I have tried moving random seed in and out of the jitted function, it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `[:]` in your code?

Comment: `numba` `random.shuffle` has a qualification, `the sequence argument must be a one-dimension Numpy array or buffer-providing object `.  It may be shuffling the fields as through they were another dimension (that may be a bug, or just a feature).  Don't expect `numba` to behave exactly like `numpy`.

Comment: @hpaulj Not using [:] wouldcause numba TypeError: TypeError: unsupported array index type Literal[str](f_id) in [Literal[str](f_id)] .

Comment: @ hapulj But the rows of the matrix, Y = X[i][:], though are of dtype array, but  just have one dimension, Y.shape = (6,) and Y.ndim = 1. Interestingly Numba didn't seem to bother me using dtype array anywhere else in my code and acted perfectly (Not shown in my question) , it's strange it's just the shuffling. Do you think I should report it as a bug?